# Texts on coalescent theory/probability methods for DNA evolution

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request, mathematical-biology

I am starting a PhD on mitochondrial evolution modelling with a focus on probabilistic methods and coalescent theory. For this purpose, I am looking for

1. advanced textbooks on probability methods for DNA evolution/coalescent theory,
2. Recent-ish (past 10 years) review articles on these topics.
3. Any lecture notes on the topic from the same period.

These are the resources I already know about:

- [Coalescent Theory: An Introduction, John Wakeley (2009)](https://books.google.co.uk/books/about/Coalescent_Theory.html?id=x30RAgAACAAJ&source=kp_book_description&redir_esc=y)
- [Probability Models for DNA Sequence Evolution, Rick Durrett (2013](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Probability_Models_for_DNA_Sequence_Evol/vIjSBwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0))
- [Some Mathematical Models From Population Genetics (published lecture notes), Alison Etheridge (2012)](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-16632-7)
- [Stochastic Models in Mathematical Genetics (Online lectures notes), Simon Myers (2020)](https://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/%7Emyers/mathgenteaching.html)

[Here is the crosspost on mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/461909/texts-on-coalescent-theory-probability-methods-for-dna-evolution)

Comment: It is a bit older than 10 years, but I really recommend the [lecture notes](https://arxiv.org/abs/0909.3985) from Berestycki on coalescent theory from 2009. Do you know what type of probabilistic models you will be looking in? For example, I am currently doing my PhD on population genetics models in the direction of Wright-Fisher, Moran, $\Lambda$-Fleming-Viot and this type of models. (These are related to Kingman and $\Lambda$-coalescents.)

Comment: Thanks, this is very much what I was looking for. It's quite early for me but the main focus is to develop a nested Moran model for application to mitochondrial DNA.